# signal functions does not recognized by octave 3.6.1

Tags: octave

I have installed Octave 3.6.1 along with packages including "signal 1.1.2" but when i run a simple example of "sigmoid_train" function an error appears "sigmoid_train function is undefined".
Can any body tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Every time I see a question with Octave 3.6.x I recommend the user install the current 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't load the signal package. When you type `pkg list` you can find which ones are loaded by an asterisk in front of their names. Load a package with `pkg load signal`.

Having to load a packages is that thing that many users coming from Matlab find strange but if you compare with other languages, such as Python, Perl, or C++, would you expect them to `import`, `use`, or `#include` every libraries available in the system by default? See [Octave's FAQ](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#I_have_installed_a_package_but_still_get_a_.22foo_undefined.22_error) for more details.

If you want a package to be loaded automatically by default, the recommended action is to add the line `pkg load signal` to your `~/.octaverc` file.

Finally, you have just started with Octave, you should had installed Octave 3.8.1.